When you just finished watching a movie, do you have to say "I loved it" or is "I love it" also correct?
I hear if someone just finished watching a movie, they say "I loved it.".
So far so good.
But I wonder is the past form (I loved it) just a preference or do you necessarily have to put it in the past tense? I mean can they also say "I love it" to mean they still love it?

I saw the Marx Brothers’ Monkey Business decades ago. Ever since then, it’s been among my favorites. I love it.

Present tense means current situation and past tense means past situation. 'I loved it' means at the specific time in the past you loved it but we don't know if you still love it. 'I love it' means at the present moment(now) you love it but we don't know if you loved it in the past or will love it in the future. That is, past is in the past and present is in the present.

@gomadeng, thanks for the comment. So, do you mean if you are not in front of the screen watching the film at the time of speaking, you can't say "I love it". Is that right?

Where you are is not important. If you now love some movie, just say "I love it". If you loved some movie in the past, just say "I loved it." Let me give you an example: I loved her. vs. I love her. If you loved her in the past then say "I loved her." If you love her now, just say "I love her." If you loved her in the past and still love her now, then just say "I still love her." or "I have loved her."

"I love that movie. I loved watching it, and would love to watch it again. " Again, time references. It's also possible to love it because you didn't love watching it, if you consider it well done but uncomfortable. (I can think of one song I have that relationship with.)

'I have loved her' sounds wrong to me if you still love her. you wouldn't say 'I have done it' if you were still doing it. you could say 'I've always loved her'.

I feel like "loved it" says more about the experience of watching the movie as you had it at the time. That can be because you love the movie, but also other factors like atmosphere, company etc.

If someone has recently watched a movie, we'd expect them to say "I loved it".
The explanation is the typical one for choosing between simple past and simple present tenses in English: past describes a completed action, present describes habitual actions or feelings.
If I watched a movie last night, I'd most likely say something like, "I watched Solaris last night - I loved it."
If I watch a movie every year, I might say something like, "I love Hannah and her Sisters - I watch it every Thanksgiving."
The expectation with the present tense is that it probably takes some time, or perhaps some number of viewings, for a movie to become habitually loved.  What amount of time, or number of viewings? That's not so clear.  But, again, that's the same basic problem with the present tense.
How many times do you need to have eaten pizza on a Friday before you can say, "I always eat pizza on Friday"?
However, there is at least one circumstance where having just viewed a movie for the first time, you can say, "I love it". Imagine a friend sits you down in front of the computer to show you a video she's just made, or even more likely, one she's still working on.  She shows you what she's done and then asks, "So, what do you think?" You could then respond, "I love it". But it also wouldn't be inappropriate to say, "I loved it".
Here, the present tense gives more of a sense of I love it so far (because it's still a work in progress), whereas the past tense suggests more of I loved it, and that's my final opinion.

It seems to me that 'loved it' is most appropriate in reference to the movie watching experience, and that 'love it' is most appropriate in reference to the movie itself. You might have only seen a movie once in your life, but if somebody asks you "what do you think of X movie", it would still be appropriate to say 'I love it', because it is about the movie (story, themes, acting, production) and not necessarily a watching experience.

Expanding on @AMcKelvy’s point, even if you’ve only just finished watching the movie, the person you watched it with could ask, “So, now you’ve seen Movie X, what do you think of it?”, and it would be perfectly natural then to say, “I love it” – because, again, you’re commenting on the movie itself, not about the experience of watching it.

@AMcKelvy I think you should make that an answer because I think it is correct. (Juhas's answer here is also correct; I think both ideas coexist.)

@AMcKelvy This also works when you watch a movie you love but hated watching it at that time because of other factors (feeling sick, loud moviegoers etc.).

Language is expressive. You use it to communicate how you feel or think about something.
If you have just watched a movie, you can say, and people do often say:

I loved it.

The meaning is something like "I enjoyed it very very much."  But you can also say, after you have just watched it:

I love it.

The meaning is something like "It is a wonderful movie and it is already on my list of wonderful movies."
The expected thing for you to say, of course, immediately after watching a movie, is "I loved it" (or "It was pretty good" or "I didn't like it") but you are leap-frogging the expectation and going directly to "It was so good that it is already in my movie pantheon!".  The very act of leap-frogging expectation expresses how much you liked it.  It  already has a place in your heart and mind.

very informative thanks.
